# How can I detect if this dictionary key exists in C#?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am working with the Exchange Web Services Managed API, with contact data. I have the following code, which is *functional*, but not ideal:

```
foreach (Contact c in contactList)
{
    string openItemUrl = "https://" + service.Url.Host + "/owa/" + c.WebClientReadFormQueryString;

    row = table.NewRow();
    row["FileAs"] = c.FileAs;
    row["GivenName"] = c.GivenName;
    row["Surname"] = c.Surname;
    row["CompanyName"] = c.CompanyName;
    row["Link"] = openItemUrl;

    //home address
    try { row["HomeStreet"] = c.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].Street.ToString(); }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    try { row["HomeCity"] = c.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].City.ToString(); }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    try { row["HomeState"] = c.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].State.ToString(); }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    try { row["HomeZip"] = c.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].PostalCode.ToString(); }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    try { row["HomeCountry"] = c.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].CountryOrRegion.ToString(); }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    //and so on for all kinds of other contact-related fields...
}
```

As I said, this code *works*. Now I want to make it suck *a little less*, if possible.

I can't find any methods that allow me to check for the existence of the key in the dictionary before attempting to access it, and if I try to read it (with `.ToString()`) and it doesn't exist then an exception is thrown:

> 500
>   The given key was not present in the dictionary.

How can I refactor this code to suck less (while still being functional)?

Answer (score 1100, accepted):

You can use [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htszx2dy.aspx):

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(key)) { ... }
```

or [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639.aspx):

```
dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
```

---

**Update**: according to a comment the actual class here is not an `IDictionary` but a [`PhysicalAddressDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.physicaladdressdictionary%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx), so the methods are [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634696%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) and [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.physicaladdressdictionary.trygetvalue%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) but they work in the same way.

Example usage:

```
PhysicalAddressEntry entry;
PhysicalAddressKey key = c.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].Street;
if (c.PhysicalAddresses.TryGetValue(key, out entry))
{
    row["HomeStreet"] = entry;
}
```

---

**Update 2:** here is the working code (compiled by question asker)

```
PhysicalAddressEntry entry;
PhysicalAddressKey key = PhysicalAddressKey.Home;
if (c.PhysicalAddresses.TryGetValue(key, out entry))
{
    if (entry.Street != null)
    {
        row["HomeStreet"] = entry.Street.ToString();
    }
}
```

...with the inner conditional repeated as necessary for each key required. The TryGetValue is only done once per PhysicalAddressKey (Home, Work, etc).

Comment: The `TryGetValue` approach seems like it may be the best bet, since I found this page: http://goo.gl/7YN6... but I'm not sure how to use it.  In my code above, `row` is a 'DataRow` object, so I'm not sure your example code is right, though...

Comment: What am I doing wrong, here? `c.PhysicalAddresses.TryGetValue(c.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].Street, row["HomeStreet"]);`

Comment: @Adam Tuttle: The second parameter is an out parameter. I'll try to guess at code that works and update my answer but you'll have to forgive mistakes as I can't compile it here.

Comment: Good answer. For consistency on SO, the term "question asker" could be replaced by "OP" (short for Original Poster).

Comment: One liner (requires `C# 7.0`) `row["HomeStreet"] = c.PhysicalAddresses.TryGetValue(PhysicalAddressKey.Home, out PhysicalAddressEntry entry) ? entry.Street.ToString() : null;`

Answer (score 17):

What is the type of `c.PhysicalAddresses`? If it's `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, then you can use the [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks, Adam, that's really (not) helpful. What's the class hierarchy? What's the base type?

Answer (score 7):

I use a Dictionary and because of the repetetiveness and possible missing keys, I quickly patched together a small method:

```
 private static string GetKey(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> dictValues, string keyValue)
 {
     return dictValues.ContainsKey(keyValue) ? dictValues[keyValue] : "";
 }
```

Calling it:

```
var entry = GetKey(dictList,"KeyValue1");
```

Gets the job done.

Answer (score 6):

[PhysicalAddressDictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.physicaladdressdictionary.trygetvalue%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

```
 public bool TryGetValue (
    PhysicalAddressKey key,
    out PhysicalAddressEntry physicalAddress
     )
```

Answer (score 5):

An improved [JohanE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363443/3094935), with generics support and as an extension method:

```cs
public static TValue GetKey<TKey, TValue>(this IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
{
    return dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key] : default;
}
```

Calling it:

```
var entry = dict.GetKey("Key");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little something I cooked up today. Seems to work for me. Basically you override the Add method in your base namespace to do a check and then call the base's Add method in order to actually add it. Hope this works for you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

namespace Main
{
    internal partial class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
    {
        internal new virtual void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
        {   
            if (!base.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                base.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
    }

    internal partial class List<T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
    {
        internal new virtual void Add(T item)
        {
            if (!base.Contains(item))
            {
                base.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dic.Add(1,"b");
            dic.Add(1,"a");
            dic.Add(2,"c");
            dic.Add(1, "b");
            dic.Add(1, "a");
            dic.Add(2, "c");

            string val = "";
            dic.TryGetValue(1, out val);

            Console.WriteLine(val);
            Console.WriteLine(dic.Count.ToString());


            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            lst.Add("b");
            lst.Add("a");
            lst.Add("c");
            lst.Add("b");
            lst.Add("a");
            lst.Add("c");

            Console.WriteLine(lst[2]);
            Console.WriteLine(lst.Count.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```