# Replace multiple Regex Matches each with a different replacement

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that may or may not have multiple matches for a designated pattern.

Each needs to be replaced.

I have this code:

```
var pattern = @"\$\$\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\b";
var stringVariableMatches = Regex.Matches(strValue, pattern);
var sb = new StringBuilder(strValue);

foreach (Match stringVarMatch in stringVariableMatches)
{
    var stringReplacment = variablesDictionary[stringVarMatch.Value];
    sb.Remove(stringVarMatch.Index, stringVarMatch.Length)
            .Insert(stringVarMatch.Index, stringReplacment);
}

return sb.ToString();
```

The problem is that when I have several matches the first is replaced and the starting index of the other is changed so that in some cases after the replacement when the string is shorten I get an index out of bounds..

I know I could just use `Regex.Replace` for each match but this sound performance heavy and wanted to see if someone could point a different solution to substitute multiple matches each with a different string.

Comment: *Regex.Replace for each match but this **sound** performance heavy* What's the size of your data?

Comment: I have around 100,000 strings like this to iterate thought .. each may have 1-3 matches to replace each with a different string.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: I think Mortalus means that using `Regex.Replace` inside the `foreach` is a performance killer. The point is that `Regex.Replace` can be used *instead* of `Regex.Matches`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I think I have misuderstood what he intended to do (and his comment on your answer confirms just that)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a Match evaluator inside the `Regex.Replace`:

```
var pattern = @"\$\$\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\b";
var stringVariableMatches = Regex.Replace(strValue, pattern, 
        m => variablesDictionary[m.Value]);
```

The `Regex.Replace` method will perform *global* replacements, i.e. will search for all non-overlapping substrings that match the indicated pattern, and will replace each found match value with the `variablesDictionary[m.Value]`.

Note that it might be a good idea to [check if the key exists in the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829873/how-can-i-detect-if-this-dictionary-key-exists-in-c).

See a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/YVJUgO):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var variablesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        variablesDictionary.Add("$$@Key", "Value");
        var pattern = @"\$\$@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b";
        var stringVariableMatches = Regex.Replace("$$@Unknown and $$@Key", pattern, 
                m => variablesDictionary.ContainsKey(m.Value) ? variablesDictionary[m.Value] : m.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(stringVariableMatches);
    }
}
```

Output: `$$@Unknown and Value`.

Comment: No worries, I carefully study profiles, look at interesting content and then vote up what is worth being voted up. Rarely, I shall say: never, the system kicked in and determined my activity to be "serial voting" ;-)