# Azure Function Optional Query Parameter

Tags: azure, azure-functions

is there a way to set optional query parameters in Azure Functions? The parameter should not be set as route parameter.
To get the query parameters i use following code snipped

`IDictionary<string, string> queryParams = req.GetQueryParameterDictionary();`

Methode signature is following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Function(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to set it as the route parameter, you can use like below:

```
string param = req.Query["param"];

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param)) { 
                //do nothing.
            } else { 
                //do something.
            }
```

Comment: hi Zhu,
doesn't this cause an exception before you get into the "if"?

Comment: @korates Please have a try.:) It will not cause exception. If it dont get specific param, then varible param will be null.(You can debug on your side.)

Comment: This implementation led to following exception: 
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException[T](T key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at

Comment: the solution was to check the input whetever it exists or not. See folowing link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829873/how-can-i-detect-if-this-dictionary-key-exists-in-c
Thank you for your answer.